# Yii - create temporary table and using it in next query produces General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active

Tags: mysql, yii

I am creating temporary table to hold some dates in first query. And in second query I try to join with those dates... and than i get following error:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute..

First query:

```
    $query = "DROP TABLE if exists TempDatesTable;";
    $query .= "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempDatesTable ( days char(20) ) TYPE=HEAP  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;";

    foreach ($allDatesInsideInterval as $date) {
        $query .= "INSERT INTO TempDatesTable VALUES( '$date' );";
    }

    Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->execute();
```

Second query

```
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                    ->select('allDays.days as periodDay, numberOfSentRequests, numberOfReceivedRequests, numOfLogins, numOfProfilesViewed')
                    ->from("(" . $commandDates->getText() . ") allDays")
                    ->leftJoin("(" . $commandProfileViewed->getText() . ") accessLog", 'allDays.days = accessLog.days')....
```

When I try to run second query:

```
return new CSqlDataProvider($command->getText(), array(
        'totalItemCount' => count($allDatesInsideInterval),
        'pagination' => array(
            'pageSize' => self::PAGE_SIZE
        ),
        ...
```

I have seen that I need to do fetchAll(); and closeCursor(); ... but how to do it in Yii?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you execute and/or fetch your data for a query, try:

```
$command = false;
```

see: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao

Comment: Seems like you might want to use $command->reset() instead: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#reset-detail

Answer (score 1):

I got same error when I have ";" in query

Try change first query

```
$query = "DROP TABLE if exists TempDatesTable;";
$query .= "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempDatesTable ( days char(20) ) TYPE=HEAP  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8";

foreach ($allDatesInsideInterval as $date) {
    $query .= "; INSERT INTO TempDatesTable VALUES( '$date' )";
}
```