# YII User Management Module install error - General error: 2014

Tags: yii

Have been trying to install this module for the past 2 days now. Its throwing up an error

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014     Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.. The SQL statement executed was: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_group` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`owner_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`participants` text NULL,
`title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`description` text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

On these lines of codes of the file: \protected\modules\user\controllers\YumInstallController.php(134): CDbCommand->execute()

```
if (isset($_POST['installUsergroup'])) {
                    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `" .   $usergroupTable . "` (
                        `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                        `owner_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
                        `participants` text NULL,
                        `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                        `description` text NOT NULL,
                        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
                            ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;";

                    $db->createCommand($sql)->execute(); //throws exception on this line. 
                    $createdTables['usergroup']['usergroupTable'] = $usergroupTable;
```

I have tried to use the line of code

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, true);
```

before running the queries. 
Have looked around, but the solutions told don't work for me. Am I missing something here?Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: Here a similar question with a solution marked as working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857378/yii-create-temporary-table-and-using-it-in-next-query-produces-general-error

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by commenting following lines in YumInstallController.PHP ( of course i am not plan to use translations)

```
// Insert the translation strings that come with yum
//$sql = file_get_contents(Yii::getPathOfAlias(
//                           'application.modules.user.docs') . '/yum_translation.sql');
//$db->createCommand($sql)->execute();
```